# Qgis Python Console, Count unique features in polygons

Tags: python, qgis

Hello I am using the python console to count the number of unique features of points in a polygon layer. Here is the link where I'm replicating the code
[link](https://docs.qgis.org/2.6/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vector_analysis_tools/countuniquepointsinpolygon.html).

Here is what my code looks like:

```
processing.runalg('qgis:countuniquepointsinpolygon', poly, pts, "fclass", "pt_count", res)
```

`poly` is my polygon layer, `pts` is my points layer, `"fclass"` is the field name in `pts` layer, `"pt_count"` will be the field where the unique feature counts will go into, and `res` is the new polygon to be created with `"pt_count"` field in it.

when I run the code I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'res' is not defined
```

the field `"fclass"` from `pts` looks like this: [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1BET7.jpg)

Is there a reason why I get this error if `res` is suppose to be created?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try passing a filename as `res`? For example:

```
processing.runalg('qgis:countuniquepointsinpolygon', poly, pts, "fclass", "pt_count", "myresult.shp")
```

Comment: yes I tried that as well, but no luck and same error message.

Comment: How can it be the same error message (`'res' is not defined`) if you replaced `res` with a literal string?

Comment: Oh my apologies, I was doing it incorrectly, I wasn't setting the path for "myresult.shp" correctly. It worked great! Thank you so much for your answer:)